# Find most occurring word in a sentence

Tags: algorithm, c, hash-map

Here is my C code for finding the most occurring word in a sentence:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ht.h"

#define MAX_WORD_LEN     1024

/*
 * Caller must call free on returned string
 * */
char* find_most_occurring_word(const char* sentence) {
    if (!sentence)
        return NULL;
    if (*sentence == '\0')
        return strdup("");

    ht* words_to_counts;
    char* ptr_word;
    int* ptr_cur_count;
    const char* sep = " ";

    words_to_counts = ht_create();
    if (!words_to_counts) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* dup_sentence = strdup(sentence);

    // tokenize sentence into words
    ptr_word = strtok(dup_sentence, sep);
    while (ptr_word != NULL) {
        ptr_cur_count = ht_get(words_to_counts, ptr_word);

        // set count as 1 if word not exists
        if (ptr_cur_count == NULL) {
            int* int_mem = malloc(sizeof(int));
            *int_mem = 1;
            ht_set(words_to_counts, ptr_word, int_mem);
        }

        // increment count if word exists
        else {
            *ptr_cur_count = *ptr_cur_count + 1;
            ht_set(words_to_counts, ptr_word, ptr_cur_count);
        }

        ptr_word = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }

    // find max occurring word by iterating the hash table
    char max_word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int max_val = INT32_MIN;
    int cur_val;
    hti words_to_counts_iterator = ht_iterator(words_to_counts);

    while (ht_next(&words_to_counts_iterator)) {
        printf("key: %s, occurrence: %d\n", words_to_counts_iterator.key, *(int*) words_to_counts_iterator.value);
        cur_val = *((int*) words_to_counts_iterator.value);
        if (cur_val > max_val) {
            max_val = cur_val;
            strcpy(max_word, words_to_counts_iterator.key);
        }
        free(words_to_counts_iterator.value);
    }

    ht_destroy(words_to_counts);
    free(dup_sentence);

    char* result = strdup(max_word);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const char* sentence = "aa aa aa bb bb bb cc cc cc cc dd dd dd dd dd";
    char* word = find_most_occurring_word(sentence);

    printf("\nword: %s", word);
    free(word);
}
```

I would like to get a general code review and hear comments and criticism about my code.

The hash table implementation is taken from [here](https://github.com/benhoyt/ht).

Comment: This does not yet take user input. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mast Good catch, that is not intentional, I'll consider getting the input sentence from an external source.

Answer (score 2):

**Good formatting**

**Inconsistent Out-of-memory handling**

After `words_to_counts = ht_create();`, code tests and on failure, prints an error message.  Yet not so with `char* dup_sentence = strdup(sentence);`

I recommend in all such places that allocation may fail, simple return `NULL`.  Let the the caller print an error if desired.

**Artificial limitation**

Yes, `MAX_WORD_LEN` makes for a quick solution, but the `strcpy(max_word, words_to_counts_iterator.key);` does not check/enforce that limit.  Better code would scale as needed.

Note: as code tokenizes the sentence, keep track of the longest word's size, then the maximum size of all words is know prior to declaring `max_word[]`.

**Only spaces?**

Rather than `const char* sep = " ";`, I'd expect any *white-space* to de-limit.

**Size to the reference object, not type**

Consider below.  The 2nd is right by construction, easier to review and maintain.

```
int_mem = malloc(sizeof(int));
// vs.
int_mem = malloc(sizeof *int_mem);
```

**Bug: Zero case**

If the string is all spaces, code attempts to `strdup(strdup(max_word))` with the uninitialized `max_word[]`: *undefined behavior* (UB).

**Sentinels**

Print with a leading and following visible character to more readily detect unexpected white-space (like `'\n'`, `'\t'`).

Print a `'\n'` at the *end*, to ensure `stdout` is printed then.  Alternative, use `fflush(stdout)`.

```
// printf("\nword: %s", word);
printf("word: \"%s\"\n", word);
```

**Types**

Code is assuming `int` and `int32_t` are the same.   Avoid that portability mistake.

```
// int max_val = INT32_MIN;
int max_val = INT_MIN;
```

A *long* string's length may exceed `iNT_MAX`, yet not `SIZE_MAX`.  Use `size_t` for string lengths and occurrence count.`

```
size_t max_val = 0;
...
// int* int_mem = malloc(sizeof(int));
size_t* count_mem = malloc(sizeof *count_mem);
```

**`strtok()` alternative**

Rather than copy the sentence with `char* dup_sentence = strdup(sentence);`, code could use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to tokenize a `const char *` maintaining an index and length.  Although this may not work with OP's `ht...()`.

**Define when needed**

Rather than define `cur_val` outside the loop, define it inside.  Better to keep objects definitions and life local as able.

```
//int cur_val;
//...
//while (...
//    cur_val = *((int*) words_to_counts_iterator.value);

while (...
    int cur_val = *((int*) words_to_counts_iterator.value);
```

**Only 1 test case**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @chux's comments, I'd point out that you don't need a pass through the hash-table.

You can simply keep track of the current highest count, and the corresponding word.

By doing this you'd also avoid any need for `MAX_WORD_LEN`...